# jQuery is not clearing the input in production environment but works in local environment in ASP.NET MVC 4.8

Tags: jquery, arrays, asp.net, model-view-controller

I have a form in ASP.NET MVC 4.8 app.   When user submit the page , user migrated to another page. Upon clicking on the back button from the browser user get back to same previous page. In this page there is a logic written in jQuery which clears the textboxes, reset the radio button.
So it works as expected but when I deploy the app and when user clicks the back arrow button from the browser then page shows all the values. Nothing get clear.

Here is the code

```
  @section Scripts{
<script language="javascript">



    $(document).ready(function () {
       
        $("#Email").val('');
        $("#Phone").val('');
        $("#Final").val(""); //I added the double quotes purposely to check if that works. 
     }
   }
```

I cleared the cache and tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some browsers don't re-run your scripts when a back/forward button is pressed. To detect when a user clicks on back/forward buttons, you can listen to `pageshow` or `pagehide` events instead of `$(document).ready()`. Try this

```
$(window).on('pageshow', function () {
    $("#Email").val('');
    $("#Phone").val('');
});
```

Comment: Thanks ruleboy21,  Your solution worked.  I just wonder, when I am working on the visual studio and run the project it worked fine based on my original code, however, same doesn't work when I deploy the same code to server. The puzzling thing is for me, I use the same Chrome on the same machine when running project locally and when deployed to production.  Also when does the window.on executes. ?